# NDSolve : Second order ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: differential-equations

I have a second order ODE of the form :

```
u''[x]+ p[x]u'[x]+ q[x] u[x]==0 ;
```

with,

```
p[x]= -(((1.15+ 4.3 x - 6 x^2))/(-0.03333333333333333 + 1.15 x + 2.15 x^2 - 2 x^3))
q[x]= ((6 -(0.06666666666666667/x^2) +(1.15/x) + 2 x))/(-0.03333333333333333+ 1.15 x + 2.15 x^2 - 2 x^3)
```

**With Boundary condition**

```
u[0]==0,u'[0]==0
```

When I solved it using NDSolve, I got the following errors :

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered. >>
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 6.+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity
encountered. >>
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`. >>
```

Could anyone please help me in solving this or similar equation ? 
Any suggestion in this regard is appreciated. Thanks in advance

I have used the following code:

```
Clear[u, t, x, eq, sol, v];
L = 6; m = -0.1; n = 1.15; k = 1.15; 
p = (-2 x^3 + (x^2) (1 + k) + n x + m/3); 
eq = -((L + (2 x + (n/x) + (2 m)/(3 x^2)) )/p) u[x] 
-D[p, x]/p D[u[x], x] +   D[D[u[x], x], x]; 
eqn = {eq == 0, u[0] == 0, D[u[x],x]/.x->0 == 0}; 
sol = NDSolve[eqn, u, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Isn't the solution $u(t) \equiv 0$?

Comment: No, actually the solution may come in the range of the order of 10^-3 or so. Here is the code i have used : Clear[u, t, x, eq, sol, v]
L = 6;
m = -0.1;
n = 1.15;
k = 1.15;
p = (-2 x^3 + (x^2) (1 + k) + n x + m/3);
eq = -((L + (2  x + (n/x) + (2 m)/(3 x^2)) )/p) u[x] - 
  D[p, x]/p D[u[x], x] + D[D[u[x], x], x];
eqn = {eq == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[eqn, u, {x, 0, 1}]

Comment: Please edit your post with the code, properly formatted, rather than put it in a comment. Comments are by design transitory on stack exchange, so it's better to have all the info in the post itself.

Comment: Well, I am posting for the first time. I have edited my post. I thank everyone for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the original code

```
eq = u''[x] + p[x] u'[x] + q[x] u[x];

p[x] = -(((1.15 + 4.3 x - 6 x^2))/(-0.03333333333333333 + 1.15 x + 
        2.15 x^2 - 2 x^3)) // Rationalize;
q[x] = ((6 - (0.06666666666666667/x^2) + (1.15/x) + 
       2 x))/(-0.03333333333333333 + 1.15 x + 2.15 x^2 - 2 x^3) // Rationalize;
```

we can use [`frobeniusNDSolve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96805), which applies [Frobenius' method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html), from my answer to [Attempting to use NDSolve to plot harmonic oscillator solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/attempting-to-use-ndsolve-to-plot-harmonic-oscillator-solutions/96805#96805), to find two independent solutions.

```
usol = frobeniusNDSolve[eq, u, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the [indicial equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndicialEquation.html) has two conjugate complex roots ${1\over2}\big(1\pm i\sqrt{7}\big)$.  We can get two independent real solutions by taking the real and imaginary parts of the Frobenius solution corresponding to one of the roots.

```
Plot[(Through[{Re, Im}@u[x]] /. First@usol) // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[(Through[{Re, Im}@u[x]] /. First@usol) // Evaluate, {x, 0, 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the value of `u[0]` is `0` in both cases, the derivative `u'[x]` approaches infinity (and is roughly asymptotic to `1/Sqrt[x]`).

```
{Through[{Re, Im}@u[0]], Through[{Re, Im}[u'[1*^-12]]]} /. First@usol
(*  {{0., 0.}, {-999941., -1.00006*10^6}}  *)
```

Consequently, the only solution satisfying the initial condition `u[0] == u'[0] == 0` is the trivial solution.

Comment: @Pisces You're welcome.

Comment: I've checked the above code with the help of  [frobeniusNDSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96805). But it shows error.

Comment: @Pisces I'll take a look when I get a chance.  I updated the code earlier, but maybe I forgot to include something.  Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Yea, Sure and no inconvenience at all. You have already helped me a lot. Thanks so much for spending your time

Comment: @Pisces I checked with a fresh kernel and the code worked without trouble. Some possibilities: Maybe you have a lurking definition that interferes with my code? Perhaps you made a change or tried a different example? What version of *Mathematica* are you using? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Pisces I see, I think: It doesn't work on your updated example.  The problem is that the indicial roots differ by an integer.  This case requires special handling that I haven't had a chance to code.  (I also haven't had a chance to code proper error messages yet.)  The error messages themselves are due to the not catching the problem in a graceful way.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Pisces To check the roots, you can execute `indicialRoots[eq, u, {x, 0}]`.